# Selecting features by attribute in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, query

Is there a way to select an individual feature based on an attribute from a FeatureGroup in Leaflet?

For example, when selecting a feature based on a click event, I will do something like,

```
function myFun(e){
    layer = e.target;
    }
```

Is there a way to do something along the lines of,

```
function myFun(uniqueID){
    layer = featureGroup WHERE featureGroup.feature.properties.ID == uniqueID;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can iterate over the layers in a `L.FeatureGroup` with `eachLayer`:

```
var match = featureGroup.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    if (layer.feature.properties.ID == uniqueID) {
        return layer
    }
})
```

[L.FeatureGroup documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup)

Comment: You need to add final ')' on the last line

Answer (score 2):

Looping through a lot of features can slow things down a lot. I add an object to store references to layers with an id as the key:

```
var layers = {};

function loadData(src) {

    d3.json(src, function(error, data) {
        if (error) return console.warn(error);

        layers = {}; // reset reference

        L.geoJSON(data, {
            style: myStyle,
            onEachFeature: eachFeature
        }).addTo(map);

    });
}

function eachFeature(feature, layer) {
    // store reference
    layers[feature.properties.id] = layer;
}
// call from outside map
function highlightFeature(id){
    layers[id].setStyle({
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Leaflet Search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-search) allows to search markers by property. It can be extended to multiple properties.